# Prolog Time Overlap Woes

Tags: prolog

Say I have this Knowledge Base:

```
free(ann,slot(time(8,0),time(9,0))).
free(ann,slot(time(10,0),time(11,0))).

free(bob,slot(time(7,0),time(8,30))).
free(bob,slot(time(10,0),time(11,0))).

free(carla,slot(time(8,0),time(9,0))).
free(carla,slot(time(10,0),time(10,15))).
```

So, after a lot of effort, I managed to write something that prints the first person who has availability during a specific slot with the following code:

```
meetone(Person, slot(time(BeginHour, BeginMinute), time(EndHour, EndMinute)))
:- free(Person, slot(time(BH, BM), time(EH, EM))),
   BH*60 + BM =< EndHour*60 + EndMinute,
   EH*60 + EM >= BeginHour*60 + BeginMinute.

main :- (meetone(Person,slot(time(7,15),time(7,20))); halt),
       write(Person),
       nl,
       halt.

:- initialization(main).
```

This prints bob, the expected result.

Here's where it gets complicated (at least for me). Let's say I want to find out all the time slots everyone in the Knowledge Base has in common. The following code demonstrates how I ultimately want to call this:

```
people([ann,bob,carla]).

meet :- ???

main :- (setof(Slot,meet(Slot),Slots); halt),
        write(Slots),
        nl,
        halt.

:- initialization(main).
```

Here's some vague pseudocode that I think might accomplish what I'm looking for, but I'm not experienced enough to get it working.

1. Start with the first person's free slots.
2. Recursively traverse the rest of the list of people, finding the overlapping times.
3. Slots can be verified to overlap using something similar to meetone; following this verification, the max of the two slot's begin times and the min of the two end times can be used to find the exact overlapping period.
4. Print the final list of slots.

The final output would show slots of 8:00 - 8:30 and 10:00 - 10:15. Any help in accomplishing this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your pseudocode is sound. You should start by writing the predicate for step 3: `overlap(S1, S2, Period)`

Comment: Yeah. I actually wrote a solution in Java first to ensure the only barrier was language unfamiliarity. I just can't seem to do it after hours and hours of attempting, and what was intended to be a fun project has instead turned into something really frustrating. I just cannot think in Prolog, and my lack of Prolog debugging skills, understanding of the flow control, etc. has been making this very challenging.

Comment: In my experience, the biggest hurdle in Prolog compared to imperative languages is feeling the difference between a function (arguments in, return value out) and a predicate (bindings in, unified bindings out).  Which is why I'm suggesting you try out with a smaller building block that works differently.  In your case, `overlap` would be called with bound slots S1 and S2, and succeed when they overlap, with the overlapping period bound to Period in the process.

Comment: When doing Prolog, forget everything you know about Java. Everything. :) Note that in Prolog, you can't compare evaluated arithmetic expressions, like `A+B =< C+D`. To evaluate arithmetically, you need the `is` operator and do it a bit more verbosely: `E1 is A+B, E2 is C+D, E1 =< E2`.

Comment: That's not the case! You can use `(=<)/2` with compound expressions, they are evaluated arithmetically just as you expect. Example: `?- 5*3 =< 2*10.` yields `true`. No need to use `(is)/2` here.

Comment: This is one of my students at Boise State University: http://cs.boisestate.edu/~buff/ He is violating the University's Academic Integrity policy. Please do not help him. I am working to expel him/her from our program. Thanks. -- Jim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prolog has some syntactic features that, imho, really help writing understandable code.
Then here is your question, taking advantage from operators to gain readability:

```
free(ann, 08:00 > 09:00).
free(ann, 10:00 > 11:00).

free(bob, 07:00 > 08:30).
free(bob, 10:00 > 11:00).

free(carla, 08:00 > 09:00).
free(carla, 10:00 > 10:15).

meetone(Person, Slot) :- free(Person, SlotP), contains(SlotP, Slot).

contains(Slot1, Slot2) :-
   timepoints(Slot1, B1, E1),
   timepoints(Slot2, B2, E2),
   B1 =< E2, E1 >= B2.

timepoints(BH:BM > EH:EM, B, E) :-
   B is BH*60 + BM,
   E is EH*60 + EM.

main :- setof(Person, meetone(Person, 7:15 > 7:20), Available),
    maplist(writeln, Available).
```

I attempted to introduce two utilities, kind of reusable code: contains/2 and timepoints/3.
Having such snippets could help while writing more complex logic...

Running this code, I get

```
?- main.
bob
true.
```

now coming to your main question:

> Let's say I want to find out all the time slots everyone in the Knowledge Base has in common

I would start writing a common_timeslot/3, explaining (computing) what's expected:

```
common_timeslot(S1, S2, Common) :-
   timepoints(S1, B1, E1),
   timepoints(S2, B2, E2), 
   % do you mean intersection by common ?
   ...
```

otherwise, consider only identity

```
common_timeslot(S, S, S).
```

Having defined this one, all commons can be found with

```
main :-
    setof(Sc/P/Q, Sp^Sq^(
        free(P, Sp), free(Q, Sq), Q \= P,
        common_timeslot(Sp, Sq, Sc)
    ), Commons),
    maplist(writeln, Commons).
```

that yields

```
?- main.
(8:0>9:0)/ann/carla
(8:0>9:0)/carla/ann
(10:0>11:0)/ann/bob
(10:0>11:0)/bob/ann
true.
```

*edit* accounting for mat comment, now I post the entire program

```
free(ann, 08:00 < 09:00).
free(ann, 10:00 < 11:00).

free(bob, 07:00 < 08:30).
free(bob, 10:00 < 11:00).

free(carla, 08:00 < 09:00).
free(carla, 10:00 < 10:15).

meetone(Person, Slot) :- free(Person, SlotP), contains(SlotP, Slot).

contains(Slot1, Slot2) :-
   timepoints(Slot1, B1, E1),
   timepoints(Slot2, B2, E2),
   B1 =< E2, E1 >= B2.

timepoints(BH:BM < EH:EM, B, E) :-
    (   ( var(B), var(E) )
    ->  B is BH * 60 + BM,
        E is EH * 60 + EM
    ;   BH is B // 60,
        BM is floor(B mod 60),
        EH is E // 60,
        EM is floor(E mod 60)
    ).

% common_timeslot(S, S, S).
common_timeslot(S1,S2,S) :-
    timepoints(S1,B1,E1),
    timepoints(S2,B2,E2),
    B is max(B1,B2),
    E is min(E1,E2),
    B < E,
    timepoints(S,B,E).

% base case: C passed all commonality test
check_common(C, [], C).

% S is the current common, to be checked for availability on person P
check_common(S, [P|Ps], C) :-
    free(P, Sp),
    common_timeslot(S, Sp, Ct),
    check_common(Ct, Ps, C).

main :- setof(P, S^free(P,S), [FirstP|Others]),
    forall(free(FirstP, S), (
        check_common(S, Others, C),
        writeln(FirstP:C)
    )).
```

that yields

```
?- main.
ann: (8:0<8:30)
ann: (10:0<10:15)
true.
```

The main change is that timepoints/3 is now 'bidirectional'. Then I introduced common_timeslot/3 as you explained in your comment.

I think you could appreciate that those small syntactic abstractions help to have a clean 'applicative' logic. Of course, [forall](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=forall/2)/2, or [setof](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=allsolutions)/3, are builtins that you need to learn about to gain more proficiency in Prolog.

Comment: Apologies for the unclarity; the final result should show just the time periods 8 - 8:30 and 10:00 - 10:15, which are the times when all three are available. (Is that what intersection by common means?) But this looks helpful, if a bit over my head right now. I'll look at it in more detail after I get some shuteye. Thanks!

Comment: +1, but `-` would in my opinion make this a lot more readable than `>`, which does not make a lot of sense especially since `8 < 9`. So `free(ann, 8:00-9:00)` seems better to me.

Comment: @mat: thanks, I'll implement following your comment, but - has the wrong precedence, qould require parentesis. I'll switch to <

Comment: Or a new infix operator `--`.

Comment: Awesome. Using GNU Prolog 1.4.4, I seem to get the following error:

uncaught exception: error(type_error(float,0),(is)/2)

Any idea where/why that might be occurring?

Comment: could be floor ? I have an older gnuprolog (ubuntu distro), and would take some time to find about the error... Try enabling ?- trace.

Comment: I didn't even know that existed. That's helpful. Here are the calls just before failure:  2    2  Exit: free(ann,8:0<9:0) ?
      3    2  Call: '$not'((check_common(8:0<9:0,[bob,carla],_75),writeln(ann:_75)),forall,2) ?
      4    3  Call: check_common(8:0<9:0,[bob,carla],_75) ?
      4    3  Exception: check_common(8:0<9:0,[bob,carla],_75) ?
      3    2  Exception: '$not'((check_common(8:0<9:0,[bob,carla],_75),writeln(ann:_75)),forall,2) ?
      1    1  Exception: main ?
uncaught exception: error(type_error(float,0),(is)/2)

Comment: I don't see the call with (is)/2, but seems (I traced with my gprolog) that's floor/1 failing...

Comment: that fails because floor/1 needs a float, and we're passing an integer. Change the expressions like `floor((B mod 60)*1.0)`, should be sufficient

Comment: All working now, thanks so much! Now I've just gotta spend more time figuring out what it all actually means. :)