# How to check Time constraint in Prolo?

Tags: time, prolog

I am a beginner in Prolog, and we have an assignment where we have to develop an incremental taxi schedule. Part of the constraints is that we're using a 24 hour system. These are my givens:

```
%taxi_info(Taxi_id, Region, BeginningTime, EndTime, Capacity, CoordinateX, CoordinateY).
taxi_info(t11, r1, 6:00, 18:00,6, 43.668943, -79.386211).
taxi_info(t12, r2, 18:00, 6:00,3, 43.668943, -79.386211).

%customer_info(Party, Name, PickUpCoordinatesX, PickUpCoordinatesY, TimeOfPickUp).
customer_info(3, 'Fox', 43.6608633, -79.4013261, 21:30).
```

Given the info here, the customer must be picked up by 21:30, and taxi t12 is the one available. How do I write that constraint?

Answer (score 0):

[this other](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19475643/874024) question had to compute with time slots, I suggested a representation similar to what have been assigned to you, and a 'service' predicate to get absolute time points.

*edit* here is the relevant code

```
timepoint(H:M, P) :-
   P is H*60 + M.
```

then your query could read (oversimplified, ignores all other constraints that don't have a representation just now)

```
?- customer_info(_Party, Name, _PickUpCoordinatesX, _PickUpCoordinatesY, TimeOfPickUp),
   timepoint(TimeOfPickUp, T),
   taxi_info(Taxi_id, _Region, BeginningTime, EndTime, _Capacity, _CoordinateX, _CoordinateY),
   timepoint(BeginningTime, B),
   timepoint(EndTime, E),
   T >= B, T < E.
```